# Nat Geo result puts paternity in doubt

Tags: dna

Nat Geo DNA test shows brothers with different paternal ancestry. One is R-Z220, the other is R-L21. Does this indicate the brothers have different fathers? The overall regional history is different too

```
66% Northwestern Europe
26% Eastern Europe
6% Northeastern Europe
    vs

32% Eastern Europe
32% Northwestern Europe
14% Southwestern Europe
10% Asia Minor
7% West Mediterranean
5% Northeastern Europe
```

Answer (score 1):

Without comprehensive results, these info is totally useless.

1. I am not specialist in R haplogroup, but if R-Z220 is subclade of R-L21 (or vice versa), your results DO NOT refute that tested persons are brothers. We need to count that some SNPs can be misread or absent in particular test.
2. About ethnicity compound. Two brothers generally share great amount of DNA, so it is not surprise if their ethnical compound will be the same. But on the other hand, two brothers may share as little DNA as 10-20%, what may lead to such a strange results that you provided.